# Change Form Option through a function with JS or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm working on an form based website.

```
<select name="foo" id="foo">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

I need to allow options to be saved by users based on previous choices.

My first attempt was to add the following HTML(with php) to the option of the users choice.

```
selected="selected"
```

However the site has some functions which change the rest of the form based on the user's choice.

```
$('#foo').change(function(event) {
....
}
```

Is it possible to have the option changed via a function(using jQuery or JS)? Thus triggering the function waiting for #foo to be changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method:

```
$('#foo').val('2');
```

which will preselct the element with `value="2"` <strike>and also trigger the change event handler</strike>. Or with pure javascript:

```
document.getElementById('foo').value = '2';
```

And to trigger the change event manually you could do this:

```
$('#foo').change();
```

Comment: Ah! You got it just before me :D

Comment: It changes the forum as did selected="selected" but did not trigger the '$('#foo').change(function(event) {...}'

Comment: @PhilipK, indeed. Changing the value doesn't seem to trigger the change event. You could trigger it manually: `$('#foo').change();`. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the value will **NOT** trigger the change event. You can just programatically trigger it by doing the following.

```
$('#foo').trigger('change');  // this should run the change code.
```